# Can I pass multiple controllers in $routeProvider.when() in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I tried searching for this on various threads, but I can't conclusively understand this.

```
test.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
    .when('/',
        {
            controller:'SimpleController1',
            templateUrl: 'partials/1.html'
        })
    .when('/xyz',
        {
            controller:'SimpleController1, SimpleController2',
            templateUrl:'partials/2.html'
        })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

I tried doing the above snippet, but it's not working. Can I do something like this? If yes, then what is it that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: whats the requirement, what do you need that??

Comment: I want to get an ajax response from a second controller based on an item from first controller's response.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only one controller is allowed and will be assigned to the loading template as the controller in `ng-view`.  No need to define `ng-controller` in the template for a main controller.

If you need to define multiple controllers I suggest you define one main/parent controller and use that in the `routeProvider` and then have others already in the template using the `ng-controller` directive.

or...

Check into using Angular UI's **UI-Router** : http://angular-ui.github.io/ which is a much more versatile router.

Comment: This is the right answer, but I'd also recommend directives, as directives can have a controller attached to them as well. Repeatable elements in particular can benefit from being setup as directives.

Comment: I figured out UI-Router enough to get started, but I still can't think of a way except creating a parent controller to pass multiple controllers.

Comment: Your last sentence implies you can do this with UI-Router, but I'm guessing, more subtly *you don't have to* with UI-Router. Which is it?