# Can we define more then one controller for a template in ng-route config function?. if yes then how?

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-ng-route

guys in the below code sample I used three controllers in the onlinetest.html template, and here I define only one controller which work fine some instance but view page contains 3 controllers. code for another controller is breaking now how I  define other two controllers in that can anyone define?.

```
 }).when("/onlinetest",{
            templateUrl:"onlinetest.html",
            controller:"quizCtrl"
        }).otherwise({
            template:"Error Page , No Match Found"
            ,redirectTo:"/"});
    });
```

Comment: Did you having a controller assigned, for instance, to a `<div>...</div>` block?

Comment: Yes, I assigned each controller in the <div> element in the template page.@FDavidov.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question. You can found right answer here

[Can I pass multiple controllers in $routeProvider.when() in angularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061540/can-i-pass-multiple-controllers-in-routeprovider-when-in-angularjs)