# Is it possible to have more than one ng-controller for one templateUrl when using .when?

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, ng-controller

Is it possible to have more than one `ng-controller` for one `templateUrl` when using `.when`? I need three different `ng-controller`s and two factories for the same `templateUrl`. I know I can have many controllers, but I don't know how to with `.when`, and I need to use `.when` because I'm using nodejs and expressjs as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I pass multiple controllers in $routeProvider.when() in angularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061540/can-i-pass-multiple-controllers-in-routeprovider-when-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest those 2 controllers inside one defined in .when in HTML template.
So, your HTML template may look like-

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl2">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl3">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so ctrl2 would go with the $routeProvider .when? and after that ctrl3 would work as well?   I have two controllers and I need to use a factory to share some data between those controllers, that's why I don't think that nested solution would work. each controller controls a different section of the html.

Comment: Ok.
So, you can simply have those two controllers initiated in HTML template without nesting.
<div ng-controller="ctrl2">
    ...
</div>
<div ng-controller="ctrl3">
    ...
</div>
like this may be.

Comment: ok and then what do I do in the $routeProvider; what should I pass to .when?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/rQTgwrTUQIUTokcbbtv5?p=preview
This might help.
In $routeProvider, you can either not pass any controller or have a controller which will be parent of both.